# A function that returns TRUE on NA, NULL, NaN in R?

Tags: r

Is there a function in R that behaves like this:

```
isnothing = function(x) {
    is.null(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x)
}
```

Comment: I really don't think there is a base function that does this. NULL and NA are two completely different things, and the test you are suggesting is sonfusing the two concepts.

Comment: The point of such a function would be defensive coding when dealing with inexperienced and/or incompetent users, of which there many in the R community.

Comment: @Backlin the go-to defence for that scenario *should be* **RTFM**. I think educating the community is better than assuming they are dumb (but +1 for your function).

Comment: @SimonO101, in most cases I agree. But in trivial situations where the intention is obvious, like producing plots, I find it better to just play ball rather than grammar policing people at my workplace. The less friction they have running my code, the more likely it is they will.

Answer (score 17):

I was also missing such a function and added this to my `.Rprofile` ages ago. If someone knows of a base function that does the same thing I also want to know.

```
is.blank <- function(x, false.triggers=FALSE){
    if(is.function(x)) return(FALSE) # Some of the tests below trigger
                                     # warnings when used on functions
    return(
        is.null(x) ||                # Actually this line is unnecessary since
        length(x) == 0 ||            # length(NULL) = 0, but I like to be clear
        all(is.na(x)) ||
        all(x=="") ||
        (false.triggers && all(!x))
    )
}
```

As @shadow mentioned, `NA`, `NaN` and `NULL` have different meanings that are important to understand. However, I find this function useful when I make functions containing optional arguments *with default values*, that I want to allow the user to suppress by setting them to any "undefined" value.

One such example is `xlab` of `plot`. I can never remember if it is `xlab=NA`, `xlab=FALSE`, `xlab=NULL` or `xlab=""`. Some produce the desired result and some don't, so I found it convenient to catch all with the above function when I develop code, particularly if other people will use it too.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are basically looking for what `gtools` invalid() function does.

```
 ?gtools::invalid
```

For example,

```
gtools::invalid(NA)
[1] TRUE
gtools::invalid(NULL)
[1] TRUE
gtools::invalid(NaN)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem too. I was trying to check whether row names of a given matrix or data frame are proper.

```
x <- matrix(1:6,ncol=2)
isnothing = function(x) {
  any(is.null(x))  | any(is.na(x))  | any(is.nan(x)) 
}
isnothing(rownames(x))
```

The function will throw an error. But when I used short circuiting and changed it to:

```
isnothing = function(x) {
  any(is.null(x))  || any(is.na(x))  || any(is.nan(x)) 
}
isnothing(rownames(x))
```

It solved my problem. I guess checking first nullity and then going forward to check other cases if it is FALSE solved my issue. I checked it with couple problematic cases that I can think of and it worked. I don't know whether there are exceptions to it but it worked for my purposes for now.

```
rownames(x) <- c("a",NaN,NA)
isnothing(rownames(x))
```